# How to compute the likelihood of a sample within a process containing gaussian and Non-gaussian noise

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution

First, I'm sorry if the topic doesn't reflect the essence of my question very well, I don't have a very good statistical background.

I've got a random variable, that is subject to two sources of noise:
$\hat{A} = A + N(\mu, \sigma) + T(\nu, \mu, \sigma)$

Sadly, the second source can not be reasonably well approximated by a normal distribution, but rather looks like a narrow - more peaked - student-t.

What I am trying to do, is to compute the Likelihood of a process sample, by plugging it into the density function of $\hat{A}$.

**Now to the Problem:**
Computing the PDF of the densities of Normal and T distributed random variables seems to be rather hard. Is there any (I don't know if conjugate is the right term here?!) distribution that I could use instead of the student-t? Or is there any way to smoothly approximate the convolution?

I'm glad to provide additional details if that helps.
Thank you!